# Excel: COUNTIFS a 2D array[A1:A100 to N1:N100] if it contains "#" if 1D array[O1:O100] contains "?"

Tags: arrays, excel

It's probably something basic, but...

In Excel, if I want a countif to run on a 2D array and exclude certain rows from a 1D array which contain x in separate column, how do I make that work?

My attempt; =COUNTIFS($A$1:$N$100,"#",$O$1:$O$100,"?")

I can't evaluate the formula since it immediately jumps into #VALUE, google doesn't help since I'm not sure how to structure the question, and I don't have elsewhere to turn. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: [Example](https://www.scribd.com/document/353578326/Rand)

Consider you wish you wish to find the total number of 2s in all columns where column G is Red.

[image: Picture of the Example]

Comment: You should get a popup warning icon; click it and choose "Show calculation steps" to see _where_ the evaluation fails. Edit the result into your question. Also consider showing example input and desired output.

Comment: Nope, nothing. I traced back the error, and it's taking me to the two arrays. The thing is, separately they work fine. If I change the 2D array to 1D, it works fine, evaluating the formula jumps straight to #Value so it gives me no further info.

Comment: Without examples of data input and desired output, we'll all just be guessing.  But in particular, I see no test for `x`, and also, the `?` is a wild card that will match any single character.

Comment: Hi, I provided an example that I hope shows the problem in its most basic form. I hope that will be satisfactory.

Comment: Generally it's preferred if you embed examples etc in your post, rather than linking to some other resource; you could upload it as an image directly into the SO editor.

Comment: Ah, I assumed it would only accept hyperlinks. Good to know it allows uploads.